# MMSE- Channel estimated based - DFE Equalization

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, digital-communications, equalization

For HF ionospheric channels ( frequency range 3 up to 30 MHz), I Want to make **channel equalization** in **time domain**, using **MMSE criterion**. I have to do it using the channel estimation.

I have some questions:

1. Can some one elaborate more on the closed-form solution solution for the feedforward and feedback FIR filters ?
2. And what is the exact relation between the number of taps of the filters and the channel delay spread ?

Any help will be really appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this PhD dissertation covers part of your question:
« Improved receivers for digital High Frequency communications: Iterative channel estimation, equalization, and decoding (adaptive turbo equalization)»
https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/249838/126139_FULLTEXT01.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Edit:
4.2 tapped delay line model, 4.11-4.13 relates the (complex baseband) tapped delay line to physical channel multipath. (p.p 57)

Comment: That is a 200 page document. You put it as an answer so I assume you read it either partially or fully and found some parts helpful, could you put those parts in your answer and leave the link as a reference?

Comment: there is a fromula to output the filter coefficients based on the MMSE criterion